# Making an iFrame responsive even though the embeded html-page isnt

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, responsive

I am not an expierenced programmer but I have an animation which is loaded in an HTML File. The animation has a fixed size and I have no clue how to make it not to be a fixed size. Making the iFrame on my HTML File responsive isnt enough because the content of it isnt.

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="centered-div">
        <iframe allowfullscreen id="door" alt="Türe" src="img_iframe/door/door.html">     </iframe>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.centered-div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1vh;
}
.centered-div iframe {
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

---

**And here is the HTML File I want to put into the iFrame:
(I have no idea what this HTML and/or this JS does, someone send it to me and wanted me to show it as an iFrame, I dont even know if this helps or not)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    NOTES:
    1. All tokens are represented by '$' sign in the template.
    2. You can write your code only wherever mentioned.
    3. All occurrences of existing tokens will be replaced by their appropriate values.
    4. Blank lines will be removed automatically.
    5. Remove unnecessary comments before creating your template.
-->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="authoring-tool" content="Adobe_Animate_CC">
<title>Tür</title>
<!-- write your code here -->
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="Tür.js?1676464100212"></script>
<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot, anim_container, dom_overlay_container, fnStartAnimation;
function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    anim_container = document.getElementById("animation_container");
    dom_overlay_container = document.getElementById("dom_overlay_container");
    var comp=AdobeAn.getComposition("5DB95DB58130B04EA74970B71B9B0348");
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    createjs.MotionGuidePlugin.install();
    var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    loader.addEventListener("fileload", function(evt){handleFileLoad(evt,comp)});
    loader.addEventListener("complete", function(evt){handleComplete(evt,comp)});
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}
function handleFileLoad(evt, comp) {
    var images=comp.getImages();
    if (evt && (evt.item.type == "image")) { images[evt.item.id] = evt.result; }
}
function handleComplete(evt,comp) {
    //This function is always called, irrespective of the content. You can use the variable "stage" after it is created in token create_stage.
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    var ss=comp.getSpriteSheet();
    var queue = evt.target;
    var ssMetadata = lib.ssMetadata;
    for(i=0; i<ssMetadata.length; i++) {
        ss[ssMetadata[i].name] = new createjs.SpriteSheet( {"images": [queue.getResult(ssMetadata[i].name)], "frames": ssMetadata[i].frames} )
    }
    exportRoot = new lib.Tür();
    stage = new lib.Stage(canvas);
    //Registers the "tick" event listener.
    fnStartAnimation = function() {
        stage.addChild(exportRoot);
        createjs.Ticker.framerate = lib.properties.fps;
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
    }
    //Code to support hidpi screens and responsive scaling.
    AdobeAn.makeResponsive(false,'both',false,1,[canvas,anim_container,dom_overlay_container]);
    AdobeAn.compositionLoaded(lib.properties.id);
    fnStartAnimation();
}
</script>
<!-- write your code here -->
</head>
<body onload="init();" style="margin:0px;">
    <div id="animation_container" style="background-color:rgba(102, 102, 51, 0.00); width:991px; height:940px">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="991" height="940" style="position: absolute; display: block; background-color:rgba(102, 102, 51, 0.00);"></canvas>
        <div id="dom_overlay_container" style="pointer-events:none; overflow:hidden; width:991px; height:940px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
(function (cjs, an) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes
var lib={};var ss={};var img={};
lib.ssMetadata = [
        {name:"Tür_atlas_1", frames: [[916,0,361,157],[0,1127,1303,651],[0,0,914,1125]]}
];


(lib.AnMovieClip = function(){
    this.actionFrames = [];
    this.ignorePause = false;
    this.gotoAndPlay = function(positionOrLabel){
        cjs.MovieClip.prototype.gotoAndPlay.call(this,positionOrLabel);
    }
    this.play = function(){
        cjs.MovieClip.prototype.play.call(this);
    }
    this.gotoAndStop = function(positionOrLabel){
        cjs.MovieClip.prototype.gotoAndStop.call(this,positionOrLabel);
    }
    this.stop = function(){
        cjs.MovieClip.prototype.stop.call(this);
    }
}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
// symbols:



(lib.CachedBmp_20 = function() {
    this.initialize(ss["Tür_atlas_1"]);
    this.gotoAndStop(0);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



(lib.CachedBmp_19 = function() {
    this.initialize(ss["Tür_atlas_1"]);
    this.gotoAndStop(1);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



(lib.CachedBmp_18 = function() {
    this.initialize(ss["Tür_atlas_1"]);
    this.gotoAndStop(2);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();
// helper functions:

function mc_symbol_clone() {
    var clone = this._cloneProps(new this.constructor(this.mode, this.startPosition, this.loop, this.reversed));
    clone.gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame);
    clone.paused = this.paused;
    clone.framerate = this.framerate;
    return clone;
}

function getMCSymbolPrototype(symbol, nominalBounds, frameBounds) {
    var prototype = cjs.extend(symbol, cjs.MovieClip);
    prototype.clone = mc_symbol_clone;
    prototype.nominalBounds = nominalBounds;
    prototype.frameBounds = frameBounds;
    return prototype;
    }


(lib.Symbol1 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
    var props = new Object();
    props.mode = mode;
    props.startPosition = startPosition;
    props.labels = {};
    props.loop = loop;
    props.reversed = reversed;
    cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

    // Layer_1
    this.instance = new lib.CachedBmp_20();
    this.instance.setTransform(0,0,0.1617,0.1617);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

    this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Symbol1, new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,58.4,25.4), null);


// stage content:
(lib.Tür = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
    var props = new Object();
    props.mode = mode;
    props.startPosition = startPosition;
    props.labels = {};
    props.loop = loop;
    props.reversed = reversed;
    cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

    // Door_top
    this.instance = new lib.CachedBmp_18();
    this.instance.setTransform(108.45,55.3,0.5,0.5);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(48));

    // Brief
    this.instance_1 = new lib.Symbol1();
    this.instance_1.setTransform(273.85,506.3,3.0913,3.0913,0,0,0,29.2,12.7);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_1).to({scaleX:3.0912,scaleY:3.0912,rotation:-1.399,guide:{path:[273.7,506.3,284.2,523.4,294.8,540.6,322.9,583.7,358.8,627.9,406.1,686,459.2,736.8], orient:'fixed'}},8).to({scaleX:3.0913,scaleY:3.0913,rotation:0,guide:{path:[459.3,736.8,535.2,809.4,623.2,867.2,637.7,875.8,652.3,884.5,672,895,693.6,904.2,708,910.2,723.2,915.7,729,917.8,735,919.9,773.5,933.1,844,956.9,844.3,957,844.6,957.1,846.2,957.7,847.8,958.2,848.4,958.4,849,958.6,849.2,958.7,849.3,958.7,849.4,958.8,849.6,958.8,854.1,960.3,858.8,961.9,861.4,962.9,864.2,963.8,871.4,966.3,879.2,968.9,880.7,969.5,882.4,970,970.5,999.3,1063.9,1027.9], orient:'fixed'}},39).wait(1));

    // Door_Bottom
    this.instance_2 = new lib.CachedBmp_19();
    this.instance_2.setTransform(14.05,613.55,0.5,0.5);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_2).wait(48));

    this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = p = new lib.AnMovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(509.6,525.3,644.6999999999999,541.9000000000001);
// library properties:
lib.properties = {
    id: '5DB95DB58130B04EA74970B71B9B0348',
    width: 991,
    height: 940,
    fps: 24,
    color: "#666633",
    opacity: 0.00,
    manifest: [
        {src:"images/Tür_atlas_1.png?1676464100177", id:"Tür_atlas_1"}
    ],
    preloads: []
};



// bootstrap callback support:

(lib.Stage = function(canvas) {
    createjs.Stage.call(this, canvas);
}).prototype = p = new createjs.Stage();

p.setAutoPlay = function(autoPlay) {
    this.tickEnabled = autoPlay;
}
p.play = function() { this.tickEnabled = true; this.getChildAt(0).gotoAndPlay(this.getTimelinePosition()) }
p.stop = function(ms) { if(ms) this.seek(ms); this.tickEnabled = false; }
p.seek = function(ms) { this.tickEnabled = true; this.getChildAt(0).gotoAndStop(lib.properties.fps * ms / 1000); }
p.getDuration = function() { return this.getChildAt(0).totalFrames / lib.properties.fps * 1000; }

p.getTimelinePosition = function() { return this.getChildAt(0).currentFrame / lib.properties.fps * 1000; }

an.bootcompsLoaded = an.bootcompsLoaded || [];
if(!an.bootstrapListeners) {
    an.bootstrapListeners=[];
}

an.bootstrapCallback=function(fnCallback) {
    an.bootstrapListeners.push(fnCallback);
    if(an.bootcompsLoaded.length > 0) {
        for(var i=0; i<an.bootcompsLoaded.length; ++i) {
            fnCallback(an.bootcompsLoaded[i]);
        }
    }
};

an.compositions = an.compositions || {};
an.compositions['5DB95DB58130B04EA74970B71B9B0348'] = {
    getStage: function() { return exportRoot.stage; },
    getLibrary: function() { return lib; },
    getSpriteSheet: function() { return ss; },
    getImages: function() { return img; }
};

an.compositionLoaded = function(id) {
    an.bootcompsLoaded.push(id);
    for(var j=0; j<an.bootstrapListeners.length; j++) {
        an.bootstrapListeners[j](id);
    }
}

an.getComposition = function(id) {
    return an.compositions[id];
}


an.makeResponsive = function(isResp, respDim, isScale, scaleType, domContainers) {
    var lastW, lastH, lastS=1;
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
    resizeCanvas();
    function resizeCanvas() {
        var w = lib.properties.width, h = lib.properties.height;
        var iw = window.innerWidth, ih=window.innerHeight;
        var pRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1, xRatio=iw/w, yRatio=ih/h, sRatio=1;
        if(isResp) {
            if((respDim=='width'&&lastW==iw) || (respDim=='height'&&lastH==ih)) {
                sRatio = lastS;
            }
            else if(!isScale) {
                if(iw<w || ih<h)
                    sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);
            }
            else if(scaleType==1) {
                sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);
            }
            else if(scaleType==2) {
                sRatio = Math.max(xRatio, yRatio);
            }
        }
        domContainers[0].width = w * pRatio * sRatio;
        domContainers[0].height = h * pRatio * sRatio;
        domContainers.forEach(function(container) {
            container.style.width = w * sRatio + 'px';
            container.style.height = h * sRatio + 'px';
        });
        stage.scaleX = pRatio*sRatio;
        stage.scaleY = pRatio*sRatio;
        lastW = iw; lastH = ih; lastS = sRatio;
        stage.tickOnUpdate = false;
        stage.update();
        stage.tickOnUpdate = true;
    }
}
an.handleSoundStreamOnTick = function(event) {
    if(!event.paused){
        var stageChild = stage.getChildAt(0);
        if(!stageChild.paused || stageChild.ignorePause){
            stageChild.syncStreamSounds();
        }
    }
}
an.handleFilterCache = function(event) {
    if(!event.paused){
        var target = event.target;
        if(target){
            if(target.filterCacheList){
                for(var index = 0; index < target.filterCacheList.length ; index++){
                    var cacheInst = target.filterCacheList[index];
                    if((cacheInst.startFrame <= target.currentFrame) && (target.currentFrame <= cacheInst.endFrame)){
                        cacheInst.instance.cache(cacheInst.x, cacheInst.y, cacheInst.w, cacheInst.h);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


})(createjs = createjs||{}, AdobeAn = AdobeAn||{});
var createjs, AdobeAn;
```

I already tried a JavaScript Library called: **reframe.js**
But it didnt solved my problem.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It looks like the iframe is hosted on the same domain as the parent page, meaning you should be able to modify the content of the iframe directly. Rather than worrying about the iframe or trying to force responsiveness from outside, you'd probably be better off just modifying the animation itself to make it responsive in the first place. Start by removing the pixel-specific width and height from the canvas element.

Comment: @DanielBeck thanks, I will try to remove pixel-specific widths and heights from the animation!

Comment: I found the problem, in the given HTML is a function called which is named makeResponsive() and the parameter "isResp" was being set on false. putting the parameter on true fixed it!

Comment: Ha!  Not often things work out that easily, that's awesome!